# How to edit a session after it's created

Tags: php, session, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon PHP and I want to add another item to my session after it's created. I have this :

```
private function _registerSession($user, $account) {
    $this->session->set('auth', array(
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'username' => $user->name
    )); }
```

In another controller I want to edit this session for example :

```
$auth = $this->session->get('auth');
$auth->add('account_id', '10');
```

And this session will content the 3 variables as :

```
    $this->session->set('auth', array(
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'username' => $user->name,
        'account_id' => 10
    )); }
```

But I don't know how I can dot that.

Comment: This doesn't work : PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function set() on a non-object

Comment: `$auth = $this->session->get('auth');
$auth['account_id']= '10';$this->session->set('auth',$auth);`

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo need to do it in following manner:-

```
$auth = $this->session->get('auth'); // get auth array from Session
$auth['account_id']= '10'; // add new index value pair to it
$this->session->set('auth',$auth); // reassign it to auth index of Session
```

Comment: Welcome @John.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$auth = $this->session->get("auth");
$this->session->set("auth", array_merge($auth, array('account_id'=>'10')));
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use like this :-

```
$auth = $this->session->get('auth'); 
$auth['account_id']= 10;
$this->session->set('auth',$auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private function _registerSession($user, $account) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('auth', array(
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'username' => $user->name
    )); }

// You should use the following code to set one more parameter in sesssion:

   $this->session->set_userdata('auth', array(
        'user_id' => $this->session_userdata('user_id'),
        'username' => $this->session_userdata('username'),
        'account_id' => 10
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon's session code is simply a wrapper around `$_SESSION`.  The simplest solution is to avoid using Phalcon functions:

```
$_SESSION['auth']->add('account_id',10);
```